# picking first value from one column and last from second based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like below
df:

```
    id  no      name        percentage  score       result
0   0   0.30    pencils     0.84        0.974185    1
1   1   0.18    computer    1.14        1.0         1
2   2   0.27    laptop      1.32        1.0         1
0   1   0.84    vegetables  1.770008    0.99992     4
1   2   0.27    meat        1.85        1.0         1
0   1   0.84    vegetables  1.770008    0.99992     4
1   2   0.27    meat        1.32        1.0         1
2   1   0.84    vegetables  1.770008    0.99992     4
3   2   0.27    fruits        1.5        1.0        1
```

I want to pick the first value of no from index_chain and last value of percentage from index_chain like below but with its original index
df1:

```
    no     
0   0.30   
0   0.84   
0   0.84
```

df2:

```
    percentage      
2    1.32    
1    1.85    
3    1.5
```

concatenated as below

```
    no     percentage subtracted
0   0.30   1.32       1.02
0   0.84   1.85       1.01
0   0.84   1.5        0.66
```

I tried like

```
    df1 = data2['no'][data2.index[0]]
    df2 = data2['percntage'][data2.index[-1]]
```

and tried to subtract

```
subtracted = dataf2 - dataf1
```

which resulted in all nan values.

I am trying this but, cannot get the index with it

Comment: What is 'index_chain'?

Comment: extreme left is the index, which is starting from 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 2 3 . this is first few entries. Some index are from 0 to 49 even long. so. I have not put all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using detecting the blocks by counting when the index drops, then `groupby`:

```
(df.groupby(df.index.to_series().diff().lt(0).cumsum())
   .agg({'no':'first', 'percentage':'last'})
   .assign(subtracted=lambda x: x['percentage'] - x['no'])
)
```

Output:

```
     no  percentage  subtracted
0  0.30        1.32        1.02
1  0.84        1.85        1.01
2  0.84        1.50        0.66
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Make sure your `no` and `percentage` are `float` type. What do you get with `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: print (df.dtypes)
no    object
percentage      object
score    object
dtype: object

Comment: So your `no` and `percentage` are not numeric, they are strings that **look like** floats. Try `df['no'] = pd.to_numeric(df['no'], errors='coerce')`, and same for `percentage` before the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Another more simple way:

```py
lowest = df.at[0, 'no'] # take all lowest values, based on index

# find maximum values based on ID
mx = df['ID'].max()
highest = df['percentage'][df['ID'] == mx]

# Create an empty dataframe, and pass highest and lowset.
output = pd.DataFrame()
output['no'] = lowest # 
output['percentage'] = highest
output['subtracted'] = output['percentage'] - output['no'] # also do the subtraction
```